# Not getting value from payload in vuex actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am usung vuex for state management
This is **my store.js** file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    loggedIn : false
},
getters: {},
mutations: {
    m_logInUser: state => {
        state.loggedIn = true;
    }
},
actions: {
    a_logInUser : ({commit}, user) => {
            alert(user.e);
            commit('m_logInUser');
    },
    a_signUpUser : ({commit}) => {
            commit('m_logInUser');
    }
}
});
```

This is the component i am using to change the state

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form_bg center-block">
        <form @submit.prevent="a_logInUser({e: email, value:100})">
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input v-model="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
            </div>
               <div class="align-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block">Log in</button>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            email: ' '
        };
    },
    computed: {
            ...mapActions([
                'a_logInUser'
            ])
    }
}
</script>
```

but the problem is when i press the login button to show an alert displaying the value entered in email i am getting undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `mapActions` in `methods`, not `computed`

Comment: I did it in computed because i want the action to take place only when there is change in value of email

Comment: Changed computed to methods and now its working but can you please explain me why not computed

Comment: Because it's a **computed property**, not a method.

Comment: You can't call / execute a property.

Comment: The vuex documentation has a explanation of form handling: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Comment: Update my comment. If you enable strict mode, write the code in setter will make sense, see the docs

Comment: yeah having a look